# How to determine the number of functional dependencies?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, functional-dependencies

Lets say I have the following table as an example
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFaq9.png)

And I am trying to determine all the functional dependencies.

Should I try all the possible dependencies by trial and error or there is another way to determine it?

Comment: You cannot expect to determine functional dependencies just from some sample data. As database designers we are normally interested in FDs as business rules: rules that should be applicable to all data, not just one set of data currently present in a table.

Comment: Please avoid images, please edit your table text into a code block.